# SWRevealViewController passing parameters

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

Passing parameters from one ViewController to other ViewController through a SWRevealViewController. This is not about passing parameter between Front Controller and  Rear Controller, but from another ViewController (firstViewController) to the front (frontViewController.
See image for reference. The segue (on button touch) tries to pass a string value to the front controller

image here: http://portwire.com/stackoverflow/storyboard.png

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SWRevealViewController *destinationViewController = (SWRevealViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    UINavigationController *navegationController = (UINavigationController *)destinationViewController.frontViewController;

    //UUPS!! SWRevealViewController.frontViewController is nil

    //How to access destination UIViewController????????

    FrontViewController * frontViewController = (FrontViewController *)navegationController.topViewController;
    frontViewController.fromString = @"String from previous view";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 3.0:

1. You have to named storyBoardId for SWRevealViewController as any thing you want, in this example: "SWRevealViewController"
2. Follow this code below:

   ```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let revealVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"SWRevealViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
   revealVc.loadView()
   let navViewController = revealVc.frontViewController as! UINavigationController
   if (navViewController.topViewController?.isKind(of: MainVc.superclass()!)) {
   let mainVc = navViewController.topViewController as! MainVc
   mainVc.email = email
   }
   self.present(revealVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I have first `LoginViewController -> SWRevealViewController -> NavigationController -> HomeViewController` (HomeViewController is the frontViewController)

From LoginViewController to SWRevealViewController I have a segue. To pass data,I use this code in `prepareForSegue` that works for me.

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"homeVC"]) {

   SWRevealViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
   [destination loadView];
   UINavigationController *navViewController = (UINavigationController *) [destination frontViewController];

   if ([navViewController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[HomeViewController class]]) {

        HomeViewController* homeVC = (HomeViewController*)navViewController.topViewController;
        homeVC.title = @"Test1";
                } }
```

Hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use delegate to do that.

Define a protocol in your front view controller and let the first view controller to conform to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your front view controller in the storyboard, it is not getting assigned in SWRevealViewController until loadView is called.  Just add

```
[destinationViewController loadView];
```

Before accessing `destinationViewController.frontViewController`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you......

```
    let revealViewCOntroller = segue.destinationViewController as! SWRevealViewController
    revealViewCOntroller.loadView()
    let secondVc = revealViewCOntroller.frontViewController as! SecondVC
    secondVc.loadView()
    secondVc.strToken = "messageToPass"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift you can do it by this way:

- First of all you could create a segue beetween a `UIButton` and a `ViewController`, to do it you should use your storyboard, choose your element and with `Ctrl` drag to your view .
- A pop-up will appear, so after that you have to choose `Custom`

[image: Pop-up segue swift]

And select the new segue on your Main.storyboard

[image]

- Then on your right board you must initialize an `Identifier` and a `Class` with `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController`

[image]

- Finally you add your param like this in your view controller.

  ```
  class NewViewController: UIViewController {
      var myParam: String!
  }
  ```

And send the param by this way:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "showMyNewView") {
            let detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! NewViewController
            detailScene.myParam = "ParamToSend"
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps,

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to declare a @property for the NSString in your frontview.

Than in segue method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetails"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DetailViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    dvc.str = @"Your current view's string";

}
}
```

Comment: No related to the question. I was asking about SWRevealViewController